# Javascript: Html2canvas callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, callback, html2canvas

I need run other my jQuery functions after Html2canvas finish own job (generate a canvas of the page).

HOW?

Piece of my code:

```
...
/* Html2canvas run code */
html2canvas(document.body, {
  onrendered: function(canvas) { document.body.appendChild(canvas); },
  width: 45
});

/* Other my jQuery functions */
$("div.mobileBody").addClass('active');
$("div.no-aside").addClass('active');
$("div.no-image").addClass('active');
```

If Html2canvas has not callback function, what JS/jQuery plugin with this image capture feature has a callback function?

Comment: Is you ,try to keep your jquey inside the `onrendred function()`?

Comment: Ok, it is working. Very and respectfully ;-) thanks.

Comment: Please add the working solution as an answer and mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

In 0.5 versions of html2canvas the solution to this is as per the [documentation](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/master/readme.md) (onrendered: is deprecated). e.g. to download the captured element:

```
html2canvas(srcEl,
  {
    canvas: scaledCanvas,
    width: originalWidth,
    height: originalHeight
  }).then(function (canvas) {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.download = "chart.png";
  a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();

});
```